# Assigning array values to subarray of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in $xml->channel->item which outputs correctly if I run:

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $entry){    
    echo $entry->title;
    echo $entry->category;
    echo $entry->pubDate;
}
```

Now, I am struggling to make this array work with the following form, which outputs a formatted table:

```
$rows = array(
 'row[0]' => array('title' => 'Test Title','category' => 'Computer', 'date' => 'test date'),
 'row[1]' => array('title' => 'Test Title 2','category' => 'Chemical', 'date' => 'test date'),
);

$form['table'] = array(
                '#type' => 'tableselect',
                '#header' => $header,
                '#options' => $rows,
        );
```

I tried this code, but it didn't work:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $rows){
    row[$i][title] = $rows->title;
    row[$i][category] = $rows->category;
    row[$i][date] = $rows->pubDate;
    $i=++;
}
```

SOLUTION:

Copying the solution I figured out from the comment below to the post body:

```
$rows = array(); 
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $entry) {
   $row['title'] = $entry->title;
   $row['category'] = $entry->category;
   $row['date'] = $entry->pubDate;

 array_push($rows, $row);
}
```

Comment: Are you missing the `$` in front of `row`? Where is `row` defined?

Comment: It the switch from `->title` to `->link` intended?

Comment: Where is the `row` array ? and if you want to increment `$i` by +1 do `$i++`

Comment: @crush, look at what I am trying to achieve: `$rows = array('row[0]'` row[0] doesn't have $ in front of it. If I put $ the table doesn't create.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out. I hope this will save others hitting the similar task:

```
$rows = array();
  foreach ($xml->channel->item as $entry) {    
   $row['title'] = $entry->title;
   $row['category'] = $entry->category;
   $row['date'] = $entry->pubDate;
array_push($rows, $row);
}
```